# Firebase Cloud Function Deployment fails with Build Error but no details

Tags: firebase, deployment, google-cloud-functions

After running

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

I get this `Build Error`:

```json
{
  "metrics": {},
  "error": {
    "buildpackId": "",
    "buildpackVersion": "",
    "errorType": "OK",
    "canonicalCode": "OK",
    "errorId": "",
    "errorMessage": ""
  },
  "stats": [
    {
      "buildpackId": "google.nodejs.runtime",
      "buildpackVersion": "1.0.0",
      "totalDurationMs": 1311,
      "userDurationMs": 0
    },
    {
      "buildpackId": "google.utils.archive-source",
      "buildpackVersion": "0.0.1",
      "totalDurationMs": 633,
      "userDurationMs": 632
    },
    {
      "buildpackId": "google.nodejs.npm",
      "buildpackVersion": "1.0.0",
      "totalDurationMs": 16330,
      "userDurationMs": 15831
    },
    {
      "buildpackId": "google.nodejs.functions-framework",
      "buildpackVersion": "0.9.4",
      "totalDurationMs": 8410,
      "userDurationMs": 7989
    },
    {
      "buildpackId": "google.config.entrypoint",
      "buildpackVersion": "0.9.0",
      "totalDurationMs": 0,
      "userDurationMs": 0
    },
    {
      "buildpackId": "google.utils.label",
      "buildpackVersion": "0.0.2",
      "totalDurationMs": 0,
      "userDurationMs": 0
    }
  ],
  "warnings": null,
  "customImage": false
}
```

How to tackle this? There seams no information anywhere, what is going wrong.

**Update**: When I try deploying a single function it works about one of ten times.

**Update**: Sometimes, instead of the `Build Error`, I get `Invalid Source Token`. No changes to the code. Just another try to deploy:

```json
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 9,
      "message": "Invalid source token"
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "witoslaw.koczewski@gmail.com"
    },
    "serviceName": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction",
    "resourceName": "projects/happygast/locations/europe-west1/functions/onWriteBenutzer"
  },
  "insertId": "-tykpquc6n0",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "happygast",
      "region": "europe-west1",
      "function_name": "onWriteBenutzer"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-09-27T18:40:55.742542Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/happygast/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
  "operation": {
    "id": "operations/aGFwcHlnYXN0L2V1cm9wZS13ZXN0MS9vbldyaXRlQmVudXR6ZXIvWUFWMXpjUEpsYk0",
    "producer": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "last": true
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-09-27T18:40:56.281792834Z"
}
```

***Update:*** A day later the problem was gone. It seams, this was a temporary issue in the cloud.

Comment: Can you try `firebase deploy --only functions --debug` and share the output?

Comment: Today the problem is gone. It seams, this was a temporary issue in the cloud.